# How to generate phase plots for the solutions of this ODE system?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

```
tmax = 500;
\[Beta]a = 0.4;
\[Beta]i = 0.3;
b = 0.55;
\[Nu] = 0.3;
\[Mu] = 0.01;
\[Rho] = 0.1;
\[Xi] = 0.001;
\[Delta]a = 0.15;
\[Delta]i = 0.41;
\[Sigma] = 0.8;
\[Tau] = 0.6;
\[Alpha] = 0.01;
SAExR = NDSolveValue[{
    S'[t] == 
     b*(1 - \[Nu]) - (\[Beta]a *A[t] + \[Beta]i *Ex[t])*
       S[t] - (\[Mu] + \[Rho])*S[t] + \[Xi] *R[t],
    A'[t] == (\[Beta]a* A[t] + \[Beta]i* Ex[t])*
       S[t] - (\[Mu] + \[Delta]a + \[Sigma])*A[t],
    Ex'[t] == \[Sigma]*A[t] - (\[Mu] + \[Delta]i + \[Tau] + \[Alpha])*
       Ex[t],
    R'[t] == 
     b*\[Nu] + \[Rho]*S[t] + \[Delta]a*A[t] + (\[Delta]i + \[Tau])*
       Ex[t] - (\[Xi] + \[Mu])*R[t],
    S[0] == 30,
    A[0] == 10,
    Ex[0] == 10,
    R[0] == 0},
   {S, A, Ex, R},
   {t, 0, tmax}];
{f1, f2, f3, f4} = SAExR;

st = Style[#, 15, Black] &;

Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t], f4[t]}, {t, 0, 50}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange, Red, Green}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Time", 20, Black], 
   Style["Density", 20, Black]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Orange, Red, Green}, {"S(t)", "A(t)", 
     "I(t)", "R(t)"}, LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.85, 0.3}], 
 ImageSize -> 500, FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black]
Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t]}, {t, 0, 50}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange, Red}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Time", 20, Black], 
   Style["Density", 20, Black]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Orange, Red}, {"S(t)", "A(t)", "I(t)"}, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.9, 0.8}], ImageSize -> 500, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black]
Plot[{f4[t]}, {t, 0, 500}, PlotStyle -> {Green}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Time", 20, Black], 
   Style["Density", 20, Black]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{ Green}, {"R(t)"}, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.9, 0.75}], ImageSize -> 500, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black]
```

How would I generate the phase plots for this system? For the example (R,S) phase plot?

Edit: Can someone create something like this but with the ***same*** plotting structure(same axis numbering, in black, same font size etc) as in the numerical simulations for the ODE system.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, a phase plot displays a function plotted against its derivative, {f,f'}. You ask for a "phase plot" of R,S, but are they derivatives of each other? Or are you asking for a parametric plot of R[t] vs. S[t]? What about Ex and A? Or {f,f'}? I'll provide you with a set of each.

I used NDSolve in place of NDSolveValue with the same constants:

```
SAExR = NDSolve[{
    S'[t] == b*(1 - \[Nu]) - (\[Beta]a *A[t] + \[Beta]i *Ex[t])* S[t] - (\[Mu] + \[Rho])*S[t] + \[Xi] *R[t],
    A'[t] == (\[Beta]a* A[t] + \[Beta]i* Ex[t])*S[t] - (\[Mu] + \[Delta]a + \[Sigma])*A[t],
    Ex'[t] == \[Sigma]*A[t] - (\[Mu] + \[Delta]i + \[Tau] + \[Alpha])*Ex[t],
    R'[t] == b*\[Nu] + \[Rho]*S[t] + \[Delta]a*A[t] + (\[Delta]i + \[Tau])*Ex[t] - (\[Xi] + \[Mu])*R[t],
    S[0] == 30, A[0] == 10, Ex[0] == 10, R[0] == 0},
   {S, A, Ex, R},{t, 0, tmax}];
```

Some of the options in your original plot are unnecessary for a ParametricPlot, so here's what's left after removing stuff like PlotLegends, etc.

```
GraphicsRow[{ParametricPlot[{S[t],R[t]}/.SAExR, {t, 0, 50}, 
 PlotStyle ->Blue, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["S[t]", 20, Black], 
   Style["R[t]", 20, Black]}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black],
ParametricPlot[{Ex[t],A[t]}/.SAExR, {t, 0, 50}, 
 PlotStyle -> Orange, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Ex[t]", 20, Black], 
   Style["A[t]", 20, Black]}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black]}]
```

[image]

ParametricPlot can phase plots (derivative of function vs function) as well. I modified your image size and aspect ratio, since the values you chose for Plot made them hard to copy/paste from my laptop.

```
 ParametricPlot[{S[t],S'[t]}/.SAExR, {t, 0, 50}, 
 PlotStyle ->Blue, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["S[t]", 20, Black], 
   Style["S'[t]", 20, Black]}, 
 ImageSize -> 350, FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black,AspectRatio->2]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[{R[t],R'[t]}/.SAExR, {t, 0, 50}, 
 PlotStyle -> Orange, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["R[t]", 20, Black], 
   Style["R'[t]", 20, Black]}, 
 ImageSize -> 350, FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black,AspectRatio->2]
```

[image]

```
 ParametricPlot[{Ex[t],Ex'[t]}/.SAExR, {t, 0, 50}, 
 PlotStyle ->Red, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Ex[t]", 20, Black], 
   Style["Ex'[t]", 20, Black]}, 
 ImageSize -> 350, FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black,AspectRatio->2]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[{A[t],A'[t]}/.SAExR, {t, 0, 50}, 
 PlotStyle -> Green, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["A[t]", 20, Black], 
   Style["A'[t]", 20, Black]}, 
 ImageSize -> 350, FrameTicksStyle -> 18, FrameStyle -> Black,AspectRatio->2]
```

[image]